# updating a date on AngularJS view

Tags: angularjs, date

I have following part in the controller after http request

```
.success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.acc = data;
        var d = new Date(data[0]['last_updated']);
        var e = d;
        var f = d;
        alert(e);
        $scope.from_date = e;
        if(typeof data[0]['duretion']=="undefined")
        {
           $scope.to_date=f.setDate(f.getDate() + 7) ;
        }
        else
        {
           $scope.to_date = f.setMonth(f.getMonth() + data[0]['duretion']);
        }  
       })
      .error(function(){

      });
```

PHP is returning values and all the values are displayed properly in front end.

The problem is when I bind `from_date` and `to_date` in the view its displaying the same date what i'm doing wrong here

Thank you

Comment: Probably nothing to do with your problem, but it's 'duration'.

Comment: try wrapping your code in $scope.$apply

Comment: @wvdz the spelling is matching with the return value so no error in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because they are both the same date object reference. Thus whatever you do to modify one reference will be reflected in the other instance

Change

```
var d = new Date(data[0]['last_updated']);
var e = d; // not a copy of `d` .. is a reference
var f = d; // not a copy of `d` .. is a reference
```

To

```
var d = new Date(data[0]['last_updated']);
var e = d;
var f = new Date(d);// make a new date object
```